# WPF Button MouseOver trigger changes background briefly

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to change the background of a button with the `IsMouseOver` trigger.  I have found many good answers on Stackoverflow but I am having a strange issue that I can't seem to find anyone else having.  I have the following style defined

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>           
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and using it with a button

```
 <Button Content="Some Button"/>
```

My problem is that when I mouse over the background changes to Purple but then immediately changes to the standard windows blue color with my mouse still over the button.  I expect that the background would stay purple until the mouse is no longer over the button.  Does anyone know what could be the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard template for a `Button` uses a [ButtonChrome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.themes.buttonchrome(v=vs.110).aspx) component, which takes care of rendering the button according to the current Windows theme. Unfortunately, the `ButtonChrome` is not very customizable (basically it does everything in its `OnRender` handler), so it you want to make bigger changes to the appearance of the button, you'll have to write a [custom template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: That is what I needed to know.